# tcpdump: always show numerical port numbers

Tags: shell, networking, c, tcpdump

The option `-n` in `tcpdump` is useful. Sometimes I prefer to see IP addresses, and sometimes I prefer to have the IP addresses resolved into hostnames.

But never do I want to have port numbers translated into "names".

How can I always show port numbers as numbers, ie `53` and not `domain`.

If this is not possible, how could I patch `tcpdump` so that port numbers are always show numerically?

I am using `tcpdump 4.9.3-1~deb10u2` on Debian 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a `-nn` flag in the `tcpdump` that ships with Linux (the flags are not portable†; Centos Linux Stream has 4.9.3 which hopefully is the same as Debian) to prevent e.g. `.22` from being shown as `.ssh`, but that also disables hostname lookups. So you're probably looking at a source code patch.

The `-n` flag is used for all sorts of things if you look at the source (`addrtoname.c`) so the simplest thing would probably be to invent a new flag, get support for that into `tcpdump.c` where the `getopt` processing happens and elsewhere (there's a struct, but you could probably just kluge in a global `int Flag_Myflag;` if you want), and then over in `addrtoname.c` modify the port conversion to not happen when your custom flag is present (there's a bunch of different ways you could combine it with `-n` or `-nn` or whatever, depending on what you want).

```
            if (Flag_Myflag) {
                    (void)snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", port);
                    table->name = strdup(buf);
            } else
                    table->name = strdup(sv->s_name);
```

Downsides: you now get to manually update and patch your custom `tcpdump` for security vulnerabilities and whatnot, or not, which has risks.

*† A coworker once tried to have me to enter Linux `tcpdump` flags; they did not know my desktop system was OpenBSD. It did not go well.*

Comment: thank you! I patched `tcpdump` and it works beautifully.

Comment: since I alredy applied one patch, would you happen to know how to patch `tcpdump`, so that instead of `8.8.8.8.53` it prints `8.8.8.8:53`? This has always irritated me that it uses `.` as IP/port separator.

Comment: it goes into the `name` field so with any luck `grep -- '->name' *.c` should find all the uses and one (or more) of those is probably the right one. might cause problems if that overlaps with other protocol (that you may not care about)